# Telegram doesn't send verification code from login widget

Tags: reactjs, telegram

I'm using a 3rd party react telegram login widget: https://github.com/hprobotic/react-telegram-login

The problem I'm having is that when i click login with telegram, it opens a popup (https://oauth.telegram.org/...) that says "Log in to use your Telegram account with
xxx and yyybot.". It asks for a phone number for verification. When I enter my phone number and hit next, nothing happens - I don't receive any dm from telegram with the confirmation.

How do I fix this?

I've also tried building it as a separate component but I'm running into the same issue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        onTelegramAuth: (user: any) => void;
    }
}


const TelegramLoginWidgetTest = ({ onAuth }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Define the onTelegramAuth callback in the global scope
        window.onTelegramAuth = (user) => {
            // Call the callback function passed in props
            onAuth(user);
        };

        // Get the target div
        const widgetDiv = document.getElementById('telegram-login-widget');
        
        // Injecting the script dynamically
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22';
        script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', 'yyybot');
        script.setAttribute('data-size', 'large');
        script.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'onTelegramAuth(user)');
        // script.setAttribute('data-auth-url', 'https://my-domain.com');
        script.setAttribute('data-request-access', 'write');
        
        if (widgetDiv) {
            widgetDiv.appendChild(script);
        }

        // Cleanup on component unmount
        return () => {
            // Clean up the global function to prevent memory leaks
            delete window.onTelegramAuth;
            if (widgetDiv) {
                widgetDiv.removeChild(script);
            }
        };
    }, [onAuth]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="telegram-login-widget"></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TelegramLoginWidgetTest;
```

Comment: I've had this same problem and never found a solution.

Comment: Hi, Have you found the solution ? Same issue rn.